# Dust protection for new NAS

Tags: cleaning, maintenance, readynas

I just got a new Netgear ReadyNAS and I am a bit worried about DUST.
What can I do to reduce the chances of dust damage ?

Would mounting it to a wall or shelf help with this ?
Can I build some surrounding (wooden?) frame with some fabric that will filter out dust ?
What sides are the most important ones to protect ?

Comment: Wood & fabric are not advisable. Dust is bad, overheating is far worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount it off the floor but with plenty of room for cooling air to circulate. Ensure it is not drawing air in over a surface on which dust settles. Regularly clean dust from the top and air intakes of the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for this, though some of them may not be safe.

- You can put vent filters, something like this:
  [image: Vent Filter]

Note that these filters may reduce the amount of the air circulation inside the device case.

- The most recommended solution (in my opinion of course), is to leave the vents as they should be, and place the NAS on a table or something, but **NOT** directly/close to the floor/under the table.

The only thing that is required by you, is to clean the vents from dust every month (or even less. It depends on how much dust you got in your area)
Make sure to clean the vents with a can of compressed air.

Comment: is compressed air better then using a vacuum? (or maybe a combination of both would be best).

Comment: also is it recommended that the device be shut down while being cleaned ?

Comment: Compressed air is better than vacuum, because it will reach for more crowded areas than the vacuum.
And yes, it is recommend to shut down the device while using these cleaning methods.

Comment: @epeleg: Take care not to spin the fans too much while cleaning as that will induce a voltage across the supply wires of the fan.